# Named lambda function in python to be used in pandas' agg function

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

The code below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
    'B': [1, 2, 3, 4, 8],
    'C': [10, 20, 30, 40, 80]})

df[['B', 'C']].agg([min, lambda x: x.quantile(0.3), max])
```

returns:

```
|          | B      C       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| min      | 1.0    10.0    |
| <lambda> | 2.2    22.0    |
| max      | 8.0    80.0    |
```

***Question:****

Is there any way that I can name the lambda function so that the name `<lambda>` is replaced by sth meaningful?

somehting similar to the code written below (this is pseudo-code and is not working):

```
df[['B', 'C']].agg([min, def pct30(x): return x.quantile(0.3), max])
```

instead of:

```
def pct30(x):
    return x.quantile(0.3)

df[['B', 'C']].agg([min, pct30, max])
```

to return:

```
|          | B      C       |
| -------- | -------------- |
| min      | 1.0    10.0    |
| pct30    | 2.2    22.0    |
| max      | 8.0    80.0    |
```

Comment: What is wrong with the second option? That seems like a good solution

Comment: The second solution (defining the function outside) works but I am curious about the capabilities of functions and trying to find a way to keep concise and find a way to define it there and still have a function name

Comment: Lambda functions are by defintion anonymous functions. You can do something ugly like `df.index.str.replace("<lambda>", "pct30")`

Comment: @Erfan it is manipulating the df after creating it. I am looking for sth simple to do it immediately. Look at my pseudo-code

Comment: This is an awful idea, but just for the sake of the question, `def named_anon(name, func): setattr(func, "__name__", name); return func`, then `df[['B', 'C']].agg([min, named_anon("pct30", lambda x: x.quantile(0.3), max)])` may work.

Answer (score 0):

first define a lambda function, then use _ *name* _
[image]

Comment: Just to add: generally it's not a good practice to assign a lambda function to a variable. Instead you should create a function like you did. But I think you shouldn't strictly follow these good practices and use something that feels good to read. In this case I find a function easier to the eye.

Comment: There is no point doing this instead of simply using a `def` statement to define `quantile30`, which will set `__name__` automatically.

Comment: Also, don't post an image of code; post the code as text.